# Get reason for Password Policy Violation from Red Hat Directory Server via UnboundID LDAPSDK

Tags: java, apache, redhat, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm trying to extract a reason why a certain password is denied, using [UnboundID LDAPSDK](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java) and connecting to [Red Hat Directory Server](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-directory-server).
However, after performing the following request:

```java
PasswordModifyExtendedRequest passwordModifyExtendedRequest = new PasswordModifyExtendedRequest(userDN, currPassword, newPassword, new Control[]{new Control("1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1")});
passwordModifyExtendedRequest.setResponseTimeoutMillis(1000);
LDAPConnection ldapConnection = ldapManager.getLdapConnection();
PasswordModifyExtendedResult extendedResult = (PasswordModifyExtendedResult) ldapConnection.processExtendedOperation(passwordModifyExtendedRequest);
System.out.println(extendedResult);
```

I get this as a response (which is not descriptive enough):

```
PasswordModifyExtendedResult(resultCode=19 (constraint violation), messageID=2, diagnosticMessage='Failed to update password', responseControls={PasswordPolicyResponseControl(errorType='insufficient password quality', isCritical=false)})
```

However, when I change the password via [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), it provides perfectly fine error message:

```
[LDAP: error code 19 - invalid password syntax - password must be at least 8 characters long]
```

Just for example, it returns the following when used on [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/) (which is fine as well):

```
[LDAP: error code 19 - CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : MODIFY_REQUEST Message ID : 15     Modify Request         Object : 'cn=josef,ou=users,o=test'             Modification[0]                 Operation :  replace                 Modification userPassword: 0x70 0x65 0x70 0x61 org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ModifyRequestImpl@196d9db6: Password should have a minimum of 5 characters]
```

**The question** is, is there a way to get the information that Apache Directory Studio manages to get? I've tried searching through their [codebase](https://github.com/apache/directory-studio), but was unable to find it.

In other words, I need to get the *"password must be at least 8 characters long"* in the response somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, using a regular `ModifyRequest` as follows:

```
// ...
import com.unboundid.util.Base64;
// ...
Modification passwordReplacementModification = new Modification(
        ModificationType.REPLACE, "userPassword",
        newPassword.getBytes());
ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(
        user.getDn(), passwordReplacementModification);
LDAPResult modifyResult = ldapManager.getLdapConnectionAsAdmin().modify(modifyRequest);
```

This results in the following exception:

```
LDAPException(resultCode=19 (constraint violation), errorMessage='invalid password syntax - password must contain at least 1 uppercase characters', diagnosticMessage='invalid password syntax - password must contain at least 1 uppercase characters', ldapSDKVersion=4.0.1, revision='26090')
```